# Easy Resource Blocking Tool

Tags: gratis, resource-management

I am looking for an very easy to use freeware tool to block resources.

Say I have a car pool of 3 cars and I want to share it with a group of people.
A person should be able to input the date and time when he / she wants to use a specific car.

The tool should be easy to use since users do not have a lot of technical experience.
Security is not really relevant, so a login would not even be necessary.

I am looking for something as easy as for instance https://doodle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple use case. Definitely there are many options to consider. Check this post for example, which lists 20 [best resource management tools](https://teamhood.com/project-management/best-resource-management-tools/) and compares them feature/pricing/UX wise.